# Installshield Express - remove REPAIR and MODIFY options

Tags: installshield, repair

we are using the Installshield which comes with visual studio, my engineer told me that it is a Installshield express

my engineer has created an installation program, if the software has already been installed, then when a user run the installation program again it shows REPAIR, MODIFY and REMOVE options.

the problem is that REPAIR and MODIFY is actually useless to me.

Can I remove these 2 options? such that when a user run the installation program while a software is already installed, it will just prompt the user to confirmation uninstall the software?

My engineer told me that this is not feasible with the bundled Installshield version. Is this true?

Thank you very much.
John

Comment: Although you want to retain the `Remove` button on this screen but this option is also redundant. Any software can always be removed from Add/Remove programs window in control panel. Better option is to simply get rid of this screen altogether which shows these three options of `Repair`, `Modify` and `Remove`. You can follow my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43869425/465053) if you want to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure if Express version has User Interface\Dialogs menu, but if has. Then it's possible, just remove Repair\Modify buttons from Maintenance dialog.